# Create new column variables based upon condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I don't know why this is not working.  I have tried it various ways and it just does not work. It's not that I get an error using the if-statements I made myself, but it doesn't apply right.

Basically, there is a column `Data$Age` and a column `Data$Age2`.

If `Data$Age` is value 50 - 100, I want `Data$Age2` to say "50-100 Years" for that particular row.

Likewise, if `Data$Age` is 25-50, I want `Data$Age2` to say "25-50 Years" for the rows to which it applies.

What would the cleanest way to go about doing this in R?

Comment: try `paste(Data$Age, "Years")`

Comment: @Onyambu I think OP means `A %in% 50:100` -> `"50-100 Years"`

Comment: @PoGibas I see what you mean, `cut(data$Age,c(25,50,100),c("25-50 years","50-100 Years"))`

Comment: @Onyambu -- need `cut(data$Age,c(24,50,100),c("25-50 years","50-100 years"))` in order for `age = 25` to be in the `25 - 50 years` category.

Comment: @Onyambu - that said, I agree `cut()` is the cleanest solution and it doesn't require extra packages.

Comment: Wow, I did not notice that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: One thing to note is that I guess there is an extra parameter in `cut` whereby you can set it =T and it will still work `cut(data$Age,c(25,50,100),c("25-50 years","50-100 years"),T)` I cant remember the name of the parameter..

Comment: @Onyambu - there are 2 arguments in `cut()` in play here: `include.lowest=` and `right=`. They work in combination, and aren't particularly intuitive.  `right=` defaults to `TRUE`, meaning that the rightmost item in the cut category is included. The problem is with the original formulation of the question, where `50` is listed in 2 categories. That said, `cut(data$Age,c(24.99,50,100),c("25-50 years","50-100 years"),right=TRUE)` also works correctly.

Comment: Yes the `include lowest.=T`  thanks. Hope will get to a computer soon and look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dplyr may have the cleanest solution to this

Using Len Greski's sample data below...

```
data <- data.frame(Age1 = round(runif(100)*100,0))

data%>%
mutate(Age2 = ifelse(between(Age1, 25, 50), "25 - 50 Years", 
              ifelse(between(Age1, 51, 100),"51 - 100 Years", "Less than 25 years old")))
```

Assuming you only want two values for the column. `ifelse()` is not efficient for more than two matches, say 100, though. I'll have to think of an alternative approach in the event that its not.

**EDIT:**
or as Len has suggested below this, in a comment.

```
data%>% 
mutate(Age2 = cut(Age1,c(24,50,100),c("25-50 years","51-100 Years")))
```

Comment: Here's the alternative approach, using the corrected version of Onyambu's solution: `data%>%
     mutate(Age2 = cut(Age1,c(24,50,100),c("25-50 years","51-100 Years")))`

Comment: The edited version worked perfect for me and I have been able to apply it to other things as well!

Answer (score 1):

So far, all the posted answers by [Len Greski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016378/3817004) and [InfiniteFlashChess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016505/3817004) in first place have suggested to use repeated subsetting statements or repeated calls to `ifelse()` for each age range.

IMHO, this can't be considered as clean because it doesn't scale well with the number of age ranges. The only data-driven solution suggested by [Onyambu in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016306/create-new-column-variables-based-upon-condition-in-r#comment83001943_48016306) is to use the `cut()` function from base R.

Here, I suggest another data-driven solution which uses a *lookup table* with the lower and upper bounds of the age ranges and the associated labels  and which *updates in a non-equi join*. This will allows us to specify an arbitrary number of ranges without any changes to the code:

```
library(data.table)
# define lookup table
lookup <- data.table(
  lower = c(25L, 51L),
  upper = c(50L, 100L)
)
lookup[, label := sprintf("%i-%i Years", lower, upper)][]
```

> ```
>    lower upper        label
> 1:    25    50  25-50 Years
> 2:    51   100 51-100 Years
> ```

```
# create sample data set
Data <- data.frame(Age = c(24:26, 49:52, 100:102))

# update in non-equi join
setDT(Data)[lookup, on =.(Age >= lower, Age <= upper), Age2 := label][]
```

> ```
>     Age         Age2
>  1:  24           NA
>  2:  25  25-50 Years
>  3:  26  25-50 Years
>  4:  49  25-50 Years
>  5:  50  25-50 Years
>  6:  51 51-100 Years
>  7:  52 51-100 Years
>  8: 100 51-100 Years
>  9: 101           NA
> 10: 102           NA
> ```

Note that `NA` indicate gaps in the age ranges defined in the lookup table.

#### Benchmarking

[InfiniteFlashChess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016306/create-new-column-variables-based-upon-condition-in-r/48020807#comment83023683_48020807) has asked about benchmark results.

Any benchmarks will depend on the number of rows in `Data` as well as on the number of groups, i.e., age ranges. So, we will do benchmark runs for 100 and 1 M rows as well as for 2 groups (as specified by the OP) and 8 groups.

The benchmark code for 2 groups:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
n_row <- 1E2L
set.seed(123L)
Data0 <- data.frame(Age = sample.int(105L, n_row, TRUE))

lookup <- data.table(
  lower = c(25L, 51L),
  upper = c(50L, 100L)
)
lookup[, label := sprintf("%i-%i Years", lower, upper)][]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ifelse = {
    copy(Data0) %>%
      mutate(Age2 = ifelse(between(Age, 25, 50), "25 - 50 Years", 
                           ifelse(between(Age, 51, 100), "51 - 100 Years", 
                                  "")))
  },
  cut = {
    copy(Data0) %>% 
      mutate(Age2 = cut(Age, c(24,50,100), c("25-50 years","51-100 Years")))
  },
  baseR = {
    data <- copy(Data0)
    data$age2 <- ""
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 51:100] <- "51 - 100 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 25:50] <- "25 - 50 years"
  },
  join_dt = {
    Data <- copy(Data0)
    setDT(Data)[lookup, on =.(Age >= lower, Age <= upper), Age2 := label]
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

Benchmark results for 100 rows:

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr      min       lq       mean    median       uq       max neval cld
>   ifelse 2280.588 2415.006 2994.83792 2501.8495 2827.513 20545.672   100   c
>      cut 2272.280 2407.455 2716.67432 2537.3425 2827.135  7351.495   100   c
>    baseR   57.016   83.446   94.80729   91.1865  106.667   164.248   100 a  
>  join_dt 1165.970 1318.889 1560.19394 1485.4025 1691.939  2803.159   100  b
> ```

Benchmark results for 1 M rows:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
>   ifelse 618.08286 626.72757 672.28875 639.04973 758.83435 773.25566    10   c
>      cut 197.16467 200.53571 219.58635 203.77460 214.24227 343.56061    10  b 
>    baseR  52.96059  59.36964  76.09431  62.19055  66.32506 198.73654    10 a  
>  join_dt  66.89256  67.61147  73.33428  72.55457  78.18675  81.69146    10 a
> ```

Benchmarking for 8 groups requires to write nested `ifelse()` or repeated subset operations:

```
breaks <- seq(20, 100, 10)

lookup <- data.table(
  lower = head(breaks, -1L),
  upper = tail(breaks, -1L)
)
lookup[, label := sprintf("%i-%i Years", lower + 1L, upper)][]


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ifelse = {
    copy(Data0) %>%
      mutate(
        Age2 = ifelse(
          between(Age, 21, 30), "21 - 20 Years", ifelse(
            between(Age, 31, 40), "31 - 40 Years", ifelse(
              between(Age, 41, 50), "41 - 50 Years", ifelse(
                between(Age, 51, 60), "51 - 60 Years", ifelse(
                  between(Age, 61, 70), "61 - 70 Years", ifelse(
                    between(Age, 71, 80), "71 - 80 Years", ifelse(
                      between(Age, 81, 90), "81 - 90 Years", ifelse(
                        between(Age, 91, 100), "91 - 100 Years", "")))))))))
  },
  cut = {
    copy(Data0) %>% 
      mutate(Age2 = cut(Age, breaks))
  },
  subset = {
    data <- copy(Data0)
    data$age2 <- ""
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 21:30] <- "21 - 30 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 31:40] <- "31 - 40 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 41:50] <- "41 - 50 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 51:60] <- "51 - 60 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 61:70] <- "61 - 70 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 71:80] <- "71 - 80 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 81:90] <- "81 - 90 years"
    data$age2[data$Age %in% 91:100] <- "91 - 100 years"
  },
  join_dt = {
    Data <- copy(Data0)
    setDT(Data)[lookup, on =.(Age > lower, Age <= upper), Age2 := label]
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

Benchmark results for 100 rows:

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>     expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval  cld
>   ifelse 2522.617 2663.832 2955.2448 2740.1030 2886.4155 7717.748   100    d
>      cut 2340.622 2470.699 2664.9381 2538.6635 2646.6520 7608.627   100   c 
>   subset  174.820  199.741  219.6505  210.5015  231.4575  402.501   100 a   
>  join_dt 1198.819 1290.949 1406.2354 1399.1255 1488.4240 1810.500   100  b
> ```

Benchmark results for 1 M rows:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>     expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
>   ifelse 2427.0599 2429.42131 2539.88611 2457.06191 2565.14682 2992.68891    10   c
>      cut  220.3553  221.53939  243.49476  222.82165  230.06289  406.57277    10  b 
>   subset  176.0096  177.92958  199.13398  184.26878  192.60274  323.90338    10  b 
>  join_dt   62.7471   64.26875   67.94099   65.07508   75.03169   75.38813    10 a
> ```

Comment: @Uwe -  Nice analysis. I agree if there are many age categories the best solution is a join.  I would not propose the extract operator solution with 8 age categories. On the other hand, the difference between .2 seconds with the `cut()` approach and 0.062 seconds on the `join_dt` approach is not substantively meaningful at the data size you tested, so `cut()` provides the best balance between parsimony of code and performance. Your analysis highlights one of the challenges of R, the diversity of solutions to a particular problem requires a fair amount of analysis to select the "best" one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using base R. Note that since `age2` cannot simultaneously be `25 - 50` and `50 - 100` I made the categories mutually exclusive:

```
data <- data.frame(age = round(runif(100)*100,0),
                   age2 = rep(" ",100),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data$age2[data$age %in% 51:100] <- "51 - 100 years"
data$age2[data$age %in% 25:50] <- "25 - 50 years"
data[1:15,]
```

...and the output:

```
> data[1:15,]
   age           age2
1    0               
2   45  25 - 50 years
3   58 51 - 100 years
4   59 51 - 100 years
5   84 51 - 100 years
6   79 51 - 100 years
7    5               
8   78 51 - 100 years
9   46  25 - 50 years
10   6               
11  73 51 - 100 years
12  37  25 - 50 years
13   5               
14  41  25 - 50 years
15  58 51 - 100 years
>
```

Comment: This is abit difficult to follow? What if the age is 30.5? How whould you deal with that? Just curious since `30.5%in%1:50` will return `FALSE` What do you think?

Comment: maybe use `findInterval(data$age,c(25,50,100),highest/right=T)` and then set the 1=="20-50" and the 2="50-100"

Comment: @Onyambu - good point. In the social sciences, `age` is usually an integer, which is why I rounded my sample data to whole numbers. If the data isn't expressed in whole numbers, a more accurate comparison is `between()`, as in `data$age2[between(data$age,25,50)] <- "25 - 50 years"`.

Comment: and why not `findInterval` ? `between` is not in base package you know.    `data$age2[findInterval(data$age,c(25,50,100)==1] <- "25 - 50 years"`

Comment: @Onyambu - `findInterval()` works as well, but `between()` is easier to understand when read by someone other than the author of the code. One of the things that really fascinates me about R is how many ways a given task can be accomplished.

Comment: @LenGreski Perhaps you might be interested in some benchmark results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48020807/3817004).